# LaTeX formula rendering

Tags: feature-request, android-app, mathjax

In the android app, looking at Math.SE, the formulas show up as raw (La)?TeX source. These should be rendered so they look look like pretty formulas:

\int_a^b f'(x) dx = f(b) - f(a)

should look like:

[image]